# Xamarin Rg.Plugins.Popup Cancel Load

Tags: xamarin.forms, popup

I'm trying to cancel the load (basically, close the popup window during loading) if I detect that there is some problem. No internet connection to retrieve the data for the popup for instance.

await PopupNavigation.PopAsync() is what is in my Close method that I normally use, but it seems like it is getting called too early.  I can still manually close the window by clicking on a Close button which invokes the Close method, but I don't want the users to have to do that.

Is there some way to abort the load, or get a notification when the page is done loading so I can programmatically exit it?

Comment: I guess it's not a Rg.Plugins.PopupPage issue. It's the same para any Page.

Comment: Sure acts like it isn't done with something, causing the PopAsync to not work at that time.  If I start a timer to issue the PopAsync, 500 ms does not work but 1000 ms does.

Comment: Yeah, and this delay should changes on each device. Maybe it's a good trick to treat it on the OnAppearing event isn't it?

Comment: I am in the OnAppearing, after the call to base.OnAppearing.  And still, no joy without a delay.  I don't want to use the delay, just trying to show that something isn't quite done.